# IE8 list formatting issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

so I have a page with some bulleted items but for some reason they are not coming in on IE8 as they should, can someone please steer me in the right direction?

http://careers.express-scripts.com/search?search=&category=&state=MO&csrf-token=

Thanks

Comment: Please put some of your code in a http://jsfiddle.net/ and then we will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have IE so can't test but my instinct says it might be to do with the text-indent and padding on the li's.

You've got:

```
#body_left ul li {
    font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    list-style: disc inside none;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 33px;
    text-indent: -1em; }
```

But you could try:

```
#body_left ul li {
    font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin-left: 33px; }
```

Comment: Yes. IE has different default values than most other browsers, so if you change one margin, all of them should be changed. and the paddings.

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out now!